# Loop through every nested child of React Children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a table component where the component will serve some special className to its specific children.

```
    const BasicTable = ({ children }) => {
        const RenderChild = Children.map(children, (el) => {
            const child = el;
    
            if (child !== null) {
                if (child.props.originalType !== "th") {
                    return <child.type {...child.props} className="th" />;
                }
    
                return <child.type {...child.props} />;
            }
            return null;
        });
    
        return (
            <div className="table-responsive">
                <table className="table w-full bg-transparent">{RenderChild}</table>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

This is my component and I want to use it like this.

```
    <BasicTable>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>dsfa</td>
                <td>dsfa</td>
                <td>dsfa</td>
                <td>dsfa</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </BasicTable>
```

But here the problem is my **Children.map** function only loop through its immediate children. How do I pass props to its nested child (th, td, ...etc)

Comment: think you have to do a check if child component is having its children and do operation you want to. eg if you are iterating over thead, check if  thead had children and if it had you can perform the action you need

Answer (score 5):

You can provide `children` prop after applying the `classNames` to the current `child`. You can define another function to apply custom class names as per your needs (The logic can be changed as per your needs).

This would also work.

```
import { Children, isValidElement } from "react";

const BasicTable = ({ children }) => {
  const RenderChild = (children) => {
    return Children.map(children, (child) => {
      if (isValidElement(child)) {
        return (
          <child.type
            {...child.props}
            children={RenderChild(child.props.children)}
            className={resolveCalssName(child.type)}
          />
        );
      }
      // non react elements (text inside the table ...etc)
      return child;
    });
  };

  const resolveCalssName = (type) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "thead":
        return "custom-thead-class-name";
      case "tbody":
        return "custom-tbody-class-name";
      case "tr":
        return "custom-tr-class-name";
      case "th":
        return "custom-th-class-name";
      case "td":
        return "custom-td-class-name";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <table className="table w-full bg-transparent">
        {RenderChild(children)}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-resonance-y5mgh?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a recursive function to iterate over all the children until thi child is `null` or is of type `string` or any other condition based on your requirement, here is an example:

```js
const BasicTable = ({ children }) => {

  const iterateOverChildren = (children) => {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      // equal to (if (child == null || typeof child == 'string'))
      if (!React.isValidElement(child)) return child;

      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        ...child.props,
        // you can alse read child original className by child.props.className
        className: child.type == 'th' ? 'th' : '',
        children: iterateOverChildren(child.props.children)})
    })
  };

  return (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <table className="table w-full bg-transparent">
        {iterateOverChildren(children)}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
      <BasicTable>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>dsfa</td>
            <td>dsfa</td>
            <td>dsfa</td>
            <td>dsfa</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </BasicTable>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.th{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```